# interacting with running svn process in emacs (win32)

Tags: svn, emacs

When trying to commit changes in emacs (win32) and svn (vc mode) I got:

```
Error validating server certificate for ...:
- The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
 fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
...
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?
```

That's OK, but how can I answer the question? When I press 'p' I got "No previous log message" line in minibuf. How to interact in emacs with running svn process?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't.  But just open a normal shell, do the svn command manually and accept the cert permanently *there*.  Then you can use emacs with that SVN server to your hearts content without having to interact with the process.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this message in Emacs (Aquamacs) vc-mode even after I did a commit in the shell and accepted the certificate, on **`OS X`**.

I ran `fs_usage -w -f filesys | egrep 'Aquamacs|svn' | tee /tmp/a.usage` to capture all filesytem activity;  on `win32` you would use `procmon` (formerly filemon), and on linux probably `strace -f /tmp/output $pid` on the emacs process...

Anyway, what I saw was `svn` looking for a certificate in `$HOME/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server/<keyfingerprint>`.  I renamed this directory, ran `svn commit` again from the command line, accepted the key permanently, and saw it re-created this file.  HOWEVER, this time the value of `ascii_cert` had a length of 1860, not 552.

Now I can `^X V V` from Emacs, and it works.  I don't know what's up with the cert, and it's complicated by me having two `svn` binaries on my path (one collabnet, the other macports), upgrading the client from 1.6 to 1.7 sometime this year, and I relocated my subversion repository root not too long ago...  so it's complicated.

But, I also couldn't find the answer to this problem when it started bugging me a couple weeks ago.  it was just some personal scripts in `~/bin` so there was no pressing need, just a minor irritant.  Finally I was irritated enough to solve my problem.  Let me know if this helps you on other platforms...